# Annuity problem, calculating the accumulated value.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

the following is the problem I am trying to work on.

> Kathryn deposits 100 into an account **at the beggining** of each 4 year period for 40 years.  The account credits interest at an effective annual interest rate of $i$. The accumulated amount in the account at the end of 40 years is $X$.  This is 5 times the accumulated amount in the account at the ned of 20 years.  Calculate $X$.

The following is what I tried.

Let $1+i^*=(1+i)^4$ so that the calculation using annuity is a bit more straight forward.

Since Kathryn deposits at the beginning of the period this is an annuity-due with 1 extra year of conversion, so letting $Y$ be the accumulated amount at the end of 20 years we can find

$$Y=100\ddot s_{\overline {5}\rceil i^*}(1+i)$$

Similarlty I think that $X$ is

$$X=100\ddot s_{\overline {10}\rceil i^*}(1+i)$$

Solving for the equation $$5Y=X$$

I think I get

$$5 = \frac{(1+i^*)^{10}-1}{(1+i^*)^5-1}$$

Fortunately this is a difference of squares so we can simply solve for $i^*$ as

$$1+i^*= \sqrt[5]{4}$$

Up to here I am somewhat confident because the problem is from EXAM FM and this artificial looking situation seems how the problem was designed, but when I use this value of $i^*$

I end up getting

$$X = 100 \frac{15}{\sqrt[5]{4}-1} (\sqrt[4]{1+\sqrt[5]{4}})\approx 5793$$

but the answer is supposedly $6195$.

Maybe I fell for a common trap, but I cannot see what I did wrong.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice work. At the end you forgot, that $1+i^*=\sqrt[5]{4}=q^*$. It is not $i^*$. Thus there is no need to add 1 under the root sign. And additonal there is no need to take the fourth root.

The equation is $X=r\cdot \frac{\left( q^* \right)^{10}-1}{q^*-1}\cdot q^* =100\cdot \frac{\left( \sqrt[5]{4} \right)^{10}-1}{\sqrt[5]{4}-1}\cdot \sqrt[5]{4}\approx 6,195$

As you see, the formula looks very familiar-to both of us.

Comment: Thank you.  Under your suggestion the numbers seem right and the problem was this.  "The end of the 20th year" in this particular problem meant "the last day of the 23rd year" which is the reason why we multiply $1+i^*$ instead of $1+i$.  I am not as good as I want to be regarding understanding which time frame they are talking about.