# Accumulated amount of annuities question - solution verification

Tags: solution-verification, finance, actuarial-science

> (Old SOA sample problem) Kathryn deposits $100$ into an account at the beginning of each $4$-year period for $40$ years. The account credits interest at an annual effective interest rate of $i$. The accumulated amount in the account at the end of $40$ years is $X$, which is $5$ times the accumulated amount in the account at the end of $20$ years.

**My attempt**: Let $j$ denote the $4$-yr annual effective rate.
$$ A(40) = X = 100 s_{10|j\%} $$
$$ A(20) = X/5 = 100 s_{5|j\%} $$

Using the formula $s_{n|j\%} = \dfrac{(1+j)^n-1}{j}$, we have

$$ \frac{(1+j)^{10} - 1}{(1+j)^5 - 1} = 5$$

Let $x = (1+j)^5$. Then we have $x^2-5x+4 = 0$, which implies $x = 4$, which leads to $(1+j) = 4^{1/5}$. So, $$ X=  \dfrac{100[(1+j)^{10}-1]}{j} \approx \dfrac{100[16-1]}{0.319} \approx 4694$$

$4694$ is one of the options, but not the correct one. I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983925/annuity-problem-calculating-the-accumulated-value), but it just confused me even more. Can someone please let me know why my solution is incorrect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is incorrect because you are using the formula for the accumulated value of an annuity-immediate, rather than an annuity-due.  Payments are made at the *beginning* of each period, not at the end.  Therefore, your solution fails to calculate the accumulated value at the correct point in time; instead, your answer $X = 4694$ represents the accumulated value at the beginning of year $17$ just after the fifth payment is made, and you need to accrue for another four years at a rate of $j = 4^{1/5} - 1 \approx 0.319508$ to obtain the correct value.  You can see that if you simply multiply your answer by $1+j$, you get the correct answer of $6195$.